# Why is EXISTS so slow compared to IN with aggregation?

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

Assume we have a table of candidate performance

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS candidates AS
WITH RECURSIVE candidates(team, score) AS (
    SELECT RANDOM() % 1000, RANDOM() % 1000000
    UNION
    SELECT RANDOM() % 1000, RANDOM() % 1000000
    FROM candidates
    LIMIT 1000000
)
SELECT team, score
FROM candidates;
```

Our goal is to output a list of the 1000 teams and the total score of candidates within that team. However, if the total score of a team is not in the first half, then it will be replaced by a zero. I came up with two ways to do this:

1. With `EXISTS`, it took **`Run Time: real 30.653 user 30.635649 sys 0.008798`**

```sql
WITH top_teams_verbose(top_team, total_score) AS (
    SELECT team, SUM(score)
    FROM candidates
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 500
)
SELECT team, SUM(score) * EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM top_teams_verbose WHERE team = top_team)
FROM candidates
GROUP BY team;
```

Query plan

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE candidates
|--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
`--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE candidates
   |  |--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
```

2. With `IN`, it took **`Run Time: real 0.045 user 0.041872 sys 0.002999`**

```sql
WITH top_teams_verbose(top_team, total_score) AS (
    SELECT team, SUM(score)
    FROM candidates
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 500
),
top_teams AS (
    SELECT top_team
    FROM top_teams_verbose
)
SELECT team, SUM(score) * (team IN top_teams)
FROM candidates
GROUP BY team;
```

Query plan

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE candidates
|--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
`--LIST SUBQUERY 3
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE candidates
   |  |--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
```

Why is it? Maybe `EXISTS` is executed for each row, whereas `IN` is used as an aggregate function? I took a look at the query plan, and the only difference (`CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY` versus `LIST SUBQUERY`) is too abstract to be informative.

I'm using SQLite3 version `3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54 3bfa9cc97da10598521b342961df8f5f68c7388fa117345eeb516eaa837bb4d6` On RHEL 7.

Comment: Pretty sure you're on track with that guess - the first one executes the exists query once per row, the other only has to calculate the list of matching rows once and look up entries in it for each row.

Comment: An index on `candidates(team)` will help both a lot, btw.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, actually an index on `candidates(team)` make the query 5 time longer (even with `ANALYZE;` executed), whereas a covering index on `candidates(team, score)` did help. See https://gist.github.com/nalzok/174c2fe365fb8729a4392aef63348fe0 for my benchmark script and its output on three different platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time for an in-depth analysis of the query plan, but it turns out that `EXISTS` causes the common table expression to re-run for each row. According to Wikipedia, this is called a [correlated query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

> In a SQL database query, a correlated subquery (also known as a synchronized subquery) is a subquery (a query nested inside another query) that uses values from the outer query. Because the subquery may be evaluated once for each row processed by the outer query, it can be slow.

Concretely, consider the following example which randomly selects 5 "lucky teams" out of a total of 10

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS candidates;


CREATE TABLE candidates AS
WITH RECURSIVE candidates(team, score) AS (
    SELECT ABS(RANDOM()) % 10, 1
    UNION
    SELECT ABS(RANDOM()) % 10, score + 1
    FROM candidates
    LIMIT 100
)
SELECT team, score
FROM candidates;


WITH lucky_teams(lucky_team, total_score) AS (
    SELECT team, SUM(score)
    FROM candidates
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 5
)
SELECT team, SUM(score) * EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM lucky_teams
    WHERE team = lucky_team
)
FROM candidates
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY team;
```

One might expect to always have 5 teams with positive scores and the rest with a score of zero, but from time to time you'll get 4 or 7 positive scores. This is because each team has an *independent* 50% chance of appearing in the `lucky_teams` table, which prevents their score from being zeroed out.

```
$ sqlite3 < quirky.sql
0|0
1|752
2|285
3|620
4|223
5|0
6|0
7|423
8|1035
9|370
```